# TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition

Tags: tfs, build, workflow, tfsbuild

I am getting an error as given below while building my workkflow in TFS

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition  
Exception Message: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Test.Activity;assembly=Test.Activity}GenerateAssemblyVersion'. (type  XamlObjectWriterException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartObject(XamlType xamlType)
 at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter   xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.FuncFactory`1.Evaluate()
 at System.Activities.DynamicActivity.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean  createEmptyBindings)
 at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean  createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
 at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity  childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining,    ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors,  ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
  at   System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity  currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions  options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
  at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity  activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment,  ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
  at  System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.InternalActivityValidati onServices.InternalValidate()
  at   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.ValidateWorkflow(Activity activity, ValidationSettings validationSettings)
   at  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildProcessCache.LoadFromXaml(String workflowXaml, TextExpressionImports textExpressionImports)
at    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareReq     uestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build,  WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
    at    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

i have tried everything as specified in the http://blog.ehn.nu/2011/12/tfs-2010-build-troubleshooting-the-tf215097-error/. But still i am stukking at the same error

Also i was able to figure out the issue is happening while i am using the below code in my Customtask

```
public sealed class Myclass: BaseCodeActivity
{
    protected override void InternalExecute()
    {
    }
  }
```

And if i use the below code able to build successfully.

```
public sealed class Myclass: CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

I was able to build both the above codes successfully in my local machine.

The BuildCodeActivity class is derived from namespace TfsBuildExtensions.Activities. So i added all the dlls which are depened on this class including the TfsBuildExtensions.Activities to the root folder where my dlls resides

I couldn't findout why the BuildCodeActivity class is throwing this error

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? It seems you are using XAML build, what kind of project are you using? Do you have successful build before? What do you change recently? How do you configure your build definition? Do all builds have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please provide more information about your environment and what you have done.
2. Create a new build definition to and queue build to see whether you can reproduce this issue.
3. Create a light project and queue build to see whether you would reproduce this issue.
4. create a new build agent to see whether you would reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi Cece. Thank you for noticing my post. I have updated the question as you said

Comment: Did you mean you are using a custom build activity? Check the links below to see whether it is helpful: http://www.hugohaggmark.com/2011/09/08/stuck-on-cannot-create-unknown-type-clr-namespace-in-tfs-build/, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec55e045-ffb2-4af9-8cad-ec51cace6cb2/tfs-2012-build-using-custom-assembly-generating-error-tftf215097-during-initialization-cannot?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Hi Cece,
i already went through it but it is not helpful for my issue.

Do you know why this issue is happening when i am using BaseCodeActivity class. ?